# what is the best way to do that name?get=

Tags: php

ok assume i have php page
has this name name.php?get= and has get varible named get
ok
how i can make it appear like that name?get=

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking here. Do you want to create a link to 'name?get=$get' or do you want to get the value of 'get' in the query string?

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd seriously reconsider before using (or overusing) mod_rewrite.

In almost all of my projects I use a simple mod rewrite in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./

AddHandler php5-script .php
```

This tells the server to forward all pages to / (index.php) unless a file otherwise exists.

In the root directory I have a folder called "views" with all of the pages that I use. E.g. the file used for /home would actually be /views/home.php. However, in the index.php I have a script that parses the user's url, checks for the file, and includes that.

```
$page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
if(!$page) :
    header("Location: /home");
if(file_exists("views/$page.php")) :
    include "views/$page.php";
else :
    include "views/$page.php";
endif;
```

This creates a variable called $page that stores the value of everything in the URL after the domain name. I use a substr() function on the Request URI to get rid of the trailing forward slash (/) on the URL.

If the variable is empty, for example if the user is simply at http://example.com or http://example.com/ then it forwards them to /home, where the script then checks for the home.php file inside of the views folder. If that file exists, it includes it, and displays it to the user.

Else, the script will simply include the 404 page telling the user that the file doesn't exist.

Hopefully this helps you, and if you need any further explanation I'd be happy to help!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using apache, mod_rewrite is one way to go. There is a whole bunch of mod_rewrite tricks [here](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php).

Answer (score 3):

I think you're wanting to re-write the URL client-side, which would include mod_rewrite.

In the route of your website, create a file called `.htaccess` and place the following code in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^name?get=(.*) /name.php?get=$1
```

Now when you type http://www.example.com/name?get=something, it will actually map to http://www.example.com/name.php?get=something transparently for you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i could understand your question, you can not strip the file extension because otherwise it will not run. In other words, you can not change:

```
name.php?get=
```

into

```
name?get=
```

But if you mean to create links with query string values that you can put them in hyperlinks in this way:

```
<a href="name.php?get=whatever">Click here !!</a>
```

Comment: Depending on the web server, you can absolutely 'strip the file extension', e.g. with mod_rewrite on Apache.

Comment: @njk You can, but it's ugly and not the ideal way of doing things. URLs then would become name?get=whatever and not name/?get=whatever.

To me, the latter seems much nicer.

Comment: Anything is possible with mod_rewrite, and in fact "name?get=" is the requirement in the above question...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to create links using a variable '$get', then you can create the link like this:

`<a href="name.php?get=$get>Link</a>`

Or if you want to get the value of the query string variable, you can use this:

`$get = $_GET['get']`